# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (C++ Inheritence Issues)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

Here's the error I'm getting upon compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for BaseClass", referenced from:
      typeinfo for DerivedOne in base-49c1cd.o
      typeinfo for DerivedTwo in base-49c1cd.o
  "vtable for BaseClass", referenced from:
      BaseClass::BaseClass() in base-49c1cd.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Here's `base.h`:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    // an enum
protected:
    float variable
public:
    float getVariable();
    void printBase();
    virtual BaseClass* clone();
    virtual float calculate(bool _one, bool _two) = 0;
};

class DerivedOne: public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedOne(float _variable);
    BaseClass* clone();
    float calculate(bool _one, bool _two);
};

class DerivedTwo: public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedTwo(float _variable);
    BaseClass* clone();
    float calculate(bool _one, bool _two);
};
```

and `base.cpp`:

```
#include "base.h"

float BaseClass::getVariable() {
    return variable;
}

void BaseClass::printBase() {
    return; // not implemented yet
}

DerivedOne::DerivedOne(float _variable) {
    variable = _variable;
}

BaseClass* DerivedOne::clone() {
    DerivedOne* tmp = new DerivedOne(variable);
    return tmp;
}

float DerivedOne::calculate(bool _one, bool _one) {
    float val = //some calculation;
    return val;
}

DerivedTwo::DerivedTwo(float _variable) {
    variable = _variable;
}

BaseClass* DerivedTwo::clone() {
    DerivedTwo* tmp = new DerivedTwo(variable);
    return tmp;
}

float DerivedTwo::calculate(bool _one, bool _two) {
    float val = //some calculation;
    return val;
}
```

I've changed the names of variables so I might have made a typo.

I think the issue I'm having stems from my lack of knowledge on constructors and abstract classes. Can anyone clear things up for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not providing implementation of `BaseClass:clone` method. Either make it pure virtual, i.e. `=0` or provide an implementation.

Error message basically tells the whole story:

> NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

You provided a declaration, but not a definition.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't really understand the difference between virtual and strictly virtual (I know this has a name). I thought I didn't need to declare the `clone()` in BaseClass seeing as it was implemented in the derived classes. Thanks!

Comment: Also, it's "pure virtual", not abstract. A class is abstract when it has (inherited or not) at least one pure virtual function. And do you really know any other way than using `=0;` to declare a member pure virtual?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following in you 'base.cpp'

```
BaseClass::BaseClass()
{
    //do something (if there's any)
}
BaseClass::~BaseClass()
{
    //do something (if there's any)
}
BaseClass::clone()
{
    //do something (if there's any)
}
```

:-)

the linker is looking for definition of your BaseClass.
If you don't write it in code like in sample above, it will produce undefined reference linker error. 
And clone(), since its not pure virtual, you need to create a default implementation for it, so that when derived classes did not create an implementation for it, the one in base class will be used.